# Using same table twice in JPA Criteria

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria-api

I Have this SQL query:

```
SELECT lf.load_factor, ls.load_incidences, avg(lsa.accumulated_load_incidences)
FROM load_factor lf
INNER JOIN load_spectrum ls ON (lf.load_factor_id = ls.load_factor_id)
INNER JOIN load_spectrum_aircraft_history lsa ON (lf.load_factor_id = lsa.load_factor_id)
INNER JOIN flight f ON (lsa.flight_id = f.flight_id)
INNER JOIN aircraft a ON (f.aircraft_id = a.aircraft_id)
WHERE a.aircraft_id = X
GROUP BY (lf.load_factor_id)
HAVING count(lf.load_factor_id) > 1;
```

On Where Clause the "X" is a variable. So, X can assume any number.

I tried to do the same Query using JPA Criteria.

So I wrote this code:

```
// Criteria Builder

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);

// ROOT
    Root<LoadSpectrumAircraftHistory> loadSpectrumAircraftRoot = query.from(LoadSpectrumAircraftHistory.class);
    Root<LoadSpectrum> loadSpectrumRoot = query.from(LoadSpectrum.class);

// JOIN Declarations
    Join<LoadSpectrumAircraftHistory, LoadFactor> loadFactor = loadSpectrumAircraftRoot.join("loadFactor");
    Join<LoadSpectrum, LoadFactor> loadSpectrum = loadSpectrumRoot.join("loadFactor");
    Join<LoadSpectrumAircraftHistory, Flight> flight = loadSpectrumAircraftRoot.join("flight");
    Join<Flight, Aircraft> aircraft = flight.join("aircraft");


// Expressions for SELECT clause
    Expression<Double> loadFactorExp = loadFactor.get("loadFactor");
    Expression<Double> loadIncidences = loadSpectrumRoot.get("loadIncidences");
    Expression<Double> accumulatedLoadIncidences = loadSpectrumAircraftRoot.get("accumulatedLoadIncidences");
    Expression<Double> avg = cb.avg(accumulatedLoadIncidences);

// Predicates for WHERE clause
    Predicate whereClause = cb.equal(aircraft.get("id"), aircraftId);

// Predicates for HAVING clause
    Predicate havingClause = cb.gt(cb.count(loadSpectrumAircraftRoot), 1);

    query.multiselect(loadFactorExp, loadIncidences, avg)
    .where(whereClause)
    .groupBy(loadFactor.get("loadFactorId"))
    .having(havingClause);

    TypedQuery<Object[]> qry = entityManager.createQuery(query);
```

But, unfortunately, this code does not generate the SQL Query as I expected.
Below there is the SQL Query generated by my JPA Code:

```
select loadfactor2_.load_factor as col_0_0_, loadspectr1_.load_incidences as col_1_0_, avg(loadspectr0_.accumulated_load_incidences) as col_2_0_ 
from load_spectrum_aircraft_history loadspectr0_ 
inner join load_factor loadfactor2_ on loadspectr0_.load_factor_id=loadfactor2_.load_factor_id 
inner join flight flight3_ on loadspectr0_.flight_id=flight3_.flight_id 
inner join aircraft aircraft4_ on flight3_.aircraft_id=aircraft4_.aircraft_id 
cross join load_spectrum loadspectr1_ inner join load_factor loadfactor5_ on loadspectr1_.load_factor_id=loadfactor5_.load_factor_id 
where aircraft4_.aircraft_id=1 
group by loadfactor2_.load_factor_id 
having count(*)>1
```

As you can see, the join between LoadSpectrum and LoadFactor is related to a new Load Factor (loadfactor5_), not the same Load Factor used in the join between LoadSpectrumAircraftHistory and LoadFactor (loadfactor2_).

They are different tables, so the factor ID is not the same for these joins.

How can I use the same table (loadfactor2_)??

*Excuse my english